# Why can an instance only be seen by main methods

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        GUI TestGUI = new GUI();

        TestGUI.setVisible(true);
    }    

    public void blahh()
    {
        TestGUI.setVisible(true);
    }
```

Can not find symbol for TestGUI in blahh, but can be seen in the main method. 
How can I access TestGUI from other methods?

Comment: A nitpick: Stick to naming conventions for variable names. `TestGUI.setVisible` looks like a static method call, but it is not. If it were a static method call, this would have worked. Use camel case, e.g. `GUI testGUI = new GUI();`

Comment: @Captain_Natty - In addition to the scope issue and naming conventions, it's also useful to distinguish between *variables* and *instances*. Variables are references that each point to an instance. Multiple variables can point to the same instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a scope issue. You could solve this by passing your GUI object to the blahh() method. Currently your blahh method has no way of reaching that variable.

```
public void blahh(GUI testGui) {
    ...
}
```

You can then call this method like this:

```
blahh(testGui);
```

Here is some [reading](https://www.baeldung.com/java-variable-scope) you can do on scope, hopefully it will be helpful

Alternatively, you could declare your testGui variable as a field, and it will be accessible from anywhere in the class (make sure to make it static if you must access it in a static method). However, this will offer you less privacy with that variable even though it might seem more convenient.

Comment: Same as the Adnan's answer, this may work depending on how the `blahh` method gets called as it's not static. But current code provided by OP doesn't include a call to this method

Answer (score 2):

because you declared TestGUI inside main method as a local varaible to a method , declare it as a class   property

```
static GUI TestGUI;   
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Test = new GUI();

    TestGUI.setVisible(true);
}    

public void blahh()
{
    TestGUI.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: this won't work. `main`is static, your variable is not

Comment: Yes, just mark the variable as static, then it will work.

Comment: This may work, depending on how the `blahh` method gets called as it's not static neither. But current code provided by OP doesn't include a call to this method

Comment: be aware, that you still can only call `blahh()` from within an instance of the class where `blahh` is declared. Currently, the time when your `main` is executed, there is no such instance - thus the method `blahh` is still inaccessible. Say your `main` is inside a class called `MyTools` then inside your `main` you would do something like `MyTools myTools = new MyTools();` and only then you have an instance of that class - then you can call `myTools.blahh()`. **But** if you set `TestGUI` to invisible (since it is static) you would set it to all instances of your class (`MyTools myTools2..)